# Non - optimal count in query generated from EF for PostGresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, count, query-optimization

I have a problem trying to optimize my ef query. I don't know what can I change even in generated sql, not mentioning mapping it to entity syntax. I would be very grateful for any optimization tips.
The query in EF:

```
var data = Context.Premise.Where(p => p.TransportManager != null);
var query = from premise in data
                        join psi in Context.PremiseSeriousInfringement on premise.Id equals psi.PremiseId
                        group psi by psi.Premise into bp
                        let types = from type in bp
                                    select type.SeriousInfringement.SeriousInfringementCode.SeriousInfringementType.Value
                        let premise = bp.Key
                        let NNInfringementCount = types.Count(t => t == "NN")
                        let BPNInfringementCount = types.Count(t => t == "BPN")
                        let PNInfringementCount = types.Count(t => t == "PN")
                        select new
                        {
                            NNInfringementCount,
                            BPNInfringementCount,
                            PNInfringementCount,
                            premise.Id,
                            premise.Type,
                            premise.Status,
                            premise.CreationDate,
                            premise.BusinessCaseNumber,

                            FirstNames = premise.TransportManager.FirstNames,
                            FamilyName = premise.TransportManager.FamilyName,
                            CertificateNumber = premise.TransportManager.CertificateNumber,

                            Types = types
                        };
query = query.OrderBy(filter.sortField + " " + filter.sortOrder)
            .Skip((filter.pageIndex - 1) * filter.pageSize)
            .Take(filter.pageSize);
```

[EDIT I have made it more readable]This is the query it generates:

```
SELECT "Project8"."UndertakingId", "Project8"."TransportManagerId", "Project8"."CancelReasons", "Project8"."WarningDate", "Project8"."WarningDeliveryDate", "Project8"."FinishDate", "Project8"."InternalProceeding", "Project8"."AuthorityId", "Project8"."PenaltyImposed", "Project8"."PenaltyDescription", "Project8"."PenaltyType", "Project8"."isSendToEpuap", "Project8"."ModificationDate", "Project8"."CreatedByAppUserId", "Project8"."LastModifiedByAppUserId", "Project8"."Id1" AS "Id", "Project8"."Id" AS "Id1", "Project8"."C2" AS "C1", "Project8"."C3" AS "C2", "Project8"."C4" AS "C3", "Project8"."Type", "Project8"."Status", "Project8"."CreationDate", "Project8"."BusinessCaseNumber", "Project8"."FirstNames", "Project8"."FamilyName", "Project8"."CertificateNumber", "Project8"."C1" AS "C4", "Project8"."Value" FROM (
SELECT "Join14"."Id", "Join14"."UndertakingId", "Join14"."TransportManagerId", "Join14"."Type", "Join14"."Status", "Join14"."CancelReasons", "Join14"."WarningDate", "Join14"."WarningDeliveryDate", "Join14"."FinishDate", "Join14"."InternalProceeding", "Join14"."AuthorityId", "Join14"."PenaltyImposed", "Join14"."PenaltyDescription", "Join14"."BusinessCaseNumber", "Join14"."PenaltyType", "Join14"."isSendToEpuap", "Join14"."CreationDate", "Join14"."ModificationDate", "Join14"."CreatedByAppUserId", "Join14"."LastModifiedByAppUserId", "Join14"."Id_Alias12" AS "Id1", "Join14"."CertificateNumber", "Join14"."FirstNames", "Join14"."FamilyName", "Join18"."Value",  CASE  WHEN ("Join18"."SeriousInfringementId" IS NULL) THEN (CAST (NULL AS int4)) ELSE (1) END  AS "C1", "Join14"."C1" AS "C2", "Join14"."C2" AS "C3", "Join14"."C3" AS "C4" FROM (
SELECT "Project7"."Id", "Project7"."UndertakingId", "Project7"."TransportManagerId", "Project7"."Type", "Project7"."Status", "Project7"."CancelReasons", "Project7"."WarningDate", "Project7"."WarningDeliveryDate", "Project7"."FinishDate", "Project7"."InternalProceeding", "Project7"."AuthorityId", "Project7"."PenaltyImposed", "Project7"."PenaltyDescription", "Project7"."BusinessCaseNumber", "Project7"."PenaltyType", "Project7"."isSendToEpuap", "Project7"."CreationDate", "Project7"."ModificationDate", "Project7"."CreatedByAppUserId", "Project7"."LastModifiedByAppUserId", "Extent18"."Id" AS "Id_Alias12", "Extent18"."CertificateNumber", "Extent18"."FirstNames", "Extent18"."FamilyName", "Project7"."C1", "Project7"."C2", "Project7"."C3" FROM (
SELECT "Project5"."Id", "Project5"."UndertakingId", "Project5"."TransportManagerId", "Project5"."Type", "Project5"."Status", "Project5"."CancelReasons", "Project5"."WarningDate", "Project5"."WarningDeliveryDate", "Project5"."FinishDate", "Project5"."InternalProceeding", "Project5"."AuthorityId", "Project5"."PenaltyImposed", "Project5"."PenaltyDescription", "Project5"."BusinessCaseNumber", "Project5"."PenaltyType", "Project5"."isSendToEpuap", "Project5"."CreationDate", "Project5"."ModificationDate", "Project5"."CreatedByAppUserId", "Project5"."LastModifiedByAppUserId", "Project5"."C1", "Project5"."C2", (
SELECT CAST (count(1) AS int4) AS "A1" FROM (
SELECT "Join12"."SeriousInfringementId", "Join12"."Id_Alias10" AS "Id", "Join12"."SeriousInfringementCodeId", "Join12"."Id_Alias11" AS "Id1", "Join12"."SeriousInfringementTypeId", "Extent17"."Id" AS "Id2", "Extent17"."Value" FROM (
SELECT "Extent16"."SeriousInfringementTypeId", "Extent13"."Id", "Extent14"."SeriousInfringementId", "Extent15"."Id" AS "Id_Alias10", "Extent15"."SeriousInfringementCodeId", "Extent16"."Id" AS "Id_Alias11" FROM "dbo"."Premise" AS "Extent13" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."PremiseSeriousInfringement" AS "Extent14" ON "Extent13"."Id" = "Extent14"."PremiseId" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringement" AS "Extent15" ON "Extent14"."SeriousInfringementId" = "Extent15"."Id" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringementCode" AS "Extent16" ON "Extent15"."SeriousInfringementCodeId" = "Extent16"."Id" WHERE "Extent13"."TransportManagerId" IS NOT NULL) AS "Join12" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."DictionaryValue" AS "Extent17" ON "Join12"."SeriousInfringementTypeId" = "Extent17"."Id" WHERE ("Project5"."Id" = "Join12"."Id" OR TRUE = FALSE) AND E'PN' = "Extent17"."Value") AS "Project6") AS "C3" FROM (
SELECT "Project3"."Id", "Project3"."UndertakingId", "Project3"."TransportManagerId", "Project3"."Type", "Project3"."Status", "Project3"."CancelReasons", "Project3"."WarningDate", "Project3"."WarningDeliveryDate", "Project3"."FinishDate", "Project3"."InternalProceeding", "Project3"."AuthorityId", "Project3"."PenaltyImposed", "Project3"."PenaltyDescription", "Project3"."BusinessCaseNumber", "Project3"."PenaltyType", "Project3"."isSendToEpuap", "Project3"."CreationDate", "Project3"."ModificationDate", "Project3"."CreatedByAppUserId", "Project3"."LastModifiedByAppUserId", "Project3"."C1", (
SELECT CAST (count(1) AS int4) AS "A1" FROM (
SELECT "Join8"."SeriousInfringementId", "Join8"."Id_Alias7" AS "Id", "Join8"."SeriousInfringementCodeId", "Join8"."Id_Alias8" AS "Id1", "Join8"."SeriousInfringementTypeId", "Extent12"."Id" AS "Id2", "Extent12"."Value" FROM (
SELECT "Extent11"."SeriousInfringementTypeId", "Extent8"."Id", "Extent9"."SeriousInfringementId", "Extent10"."Id" AS "Id_Alias7", "Extent10"."SeriousInfringementCodeId", "Extent11"."Id" AS "Id_Alias8" FROM "dbo"."Premise" AS "Extent8" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."PremiseSeriousInfringement" AS "Extent9" ON "Extent8"."Id" = "Extent9"."PremiseId" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringement" AS "Extent10" ON "Extent9"."SeriousInfringementId" = "Extent10"."Id" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringementCode" AS "Extent11" ON "Extent10"."SeriousInfringementCodeId" = "Extent11"."Id" WHERE "Extent8"."TransportManagerId" IS NOT NULL) AS "Join8" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."DictionaryValue" AS "Extent12" ON "Join8"."SeriousInfringementTypeId" = "Extent12"."Id" WHERE ("Project3"."Id" = "Join8"."Id" OR TRUE = FALSE) AND E'BPN' = "Extent12"."Value") AS "Project4") AS "C2" FROM (
SELECT "Alias2"."Id", "Alias2"."UndertakingId", "Alias2"."TransportManagerId", "Alias2"."Type", "Alias2"."Status", "Alias2"."CancelReasons", "Alias2"."WarningDate", "Alias2"."WarningDeliveryDate", "Alias2"."FinishDate", "Alias2"."InternalProceeding", "Alias2"."AuthorityId", "Alias2"."PenaltyImposed", "Alias2"."PenaltyDescription", "Alias2"."BusinessCaseNumber", "Alias2"."PenaltyType", "Alias2"."isSendToEpuap", "Alias2"."CreationDate", "Alias2"."ModificationDate", "Alias2"."CreatedByAppUserId", "Alias2"."LastModifiedByAppUserId", (
SELECT CAST (count(1) AS int4) AS "A1" FROM (
SELECT "Join4"."SeriousInfringementId", "Join4"."Id_Alias4" AS "Id", "Join4"."SeriousInfringementCodeId", "Join4"."Id_Alias5" AS "Id1", "Join4"."SeriousInfringementTypeId", "Extent7"."Id" AS "Id2", "Extent7"."Value" FROM (
SELECT "Extent6"."SeriousInfringementTypeId", "Extent3"."Id", "Extent4"."SeriousInfringementId", "Extent5"."Id" AS "Id_Alias4", "Extent5"."SeriousInfringementCodeId", "Extent6"."Id" AS "Id_Alias5" FROM "dbo"."Premise" AS "Extent3" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."PremiseSeriousInfringement" AS "Extent4" ON "Extent3"."Id" = "Extent4"."PremiseId" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringement" AS "Extent5" ON "Extent4"."SeriousInfringementId" = "Extent5"."Id" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringementCode" AS "Extent6" ON "Extent5"."SeriousInfringementCodeId" = "Extent6"."Id" WHERE "Extent3"."TransportManagerId" IS NOT NULL) AS "Join4" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."DictionaryValue" AS "Extent7" ON "Join4"."SeriousInfringementTypeId" = "Extent7"."Id" WHERE ("Alias2"."Id" = "Join4"."Id" OR TRUE = FALSE) AND E'NN' = "Extent7"."Value") AS "Project2") AS "C1" FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT "Extent1"."Id", "Extent1"."UndertakingId", "Extent1"."TransportManagerId", "Extent1"."Type", "Extent1"."Status", "Extent1"."CancelReasons", "Extent1"."WarningDate", "Extent1"."WarningDeliveryDate", "Extent1"."FinishDate", "Extent1"."InternalProceeding", "Extent1"."AuthorityId", "Extent1"."PenaltyImposed", "Extent1"."PenaltyDescription", "Extent1"."BusinessCaseNumber", "Extent1"."PenaltyType", "Extent1"."isSendToEpuap", "Extent1"."CreationDate", "Extent1"."ModificationDate", "Extent1"."CreatedByAppUserId", "Extent1"."LastModifiedByAppUserId" FROM "dbo"."Premise" AS "Extent1" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."PremiseSeriousInfringement" AS "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."Id" = "Extent2"."PremiseId" AND "Extent2"."PremiseId" = "Extent1"."Id" WHERE "Extent1"."TransportManagerId" IS NOT NULL) AS "Alias2") AS "Project3") AS "Project5") AS "Project7" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."TransportManager" AS "Extent18" ON "Project7"."TransportManagerId" = "Extent18"."Id" ORDER BY "Project7"."Type" ASC  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25) AS "Join14" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT "Extent19"."Id", "Extent23"."Value", "Extent20"."SeriousInfringementId" FROM "dbo"."Premise" AS "Extent19" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."PremiseSeriousInfringement" AS "Extent20" ON "Extent19"."Id" = "Extent20"."PremiseId" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringement" AS "Extent21" ON "Extent20"."SeriousInfringementId" = "Extent21"."Id" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."SeriousInfringementCode" AS "Extent22" ON "Extent21"."SeriousInfringementCodeId" = "Extent22"."Id" 
INNER JOIN "dbo"."DictionaryValue" AS "Extent23" ON "Extent22"."SeriousInfringementTypeId" = "Extent23"."Id" WHERE "Extent19"."TransportManagerId" IS NOT NULL) AS "Join18" ON "Join14"."Id" = "Join18"."Id" OR TRUE = FALSE) AS "Project8" ORDER BY "Project8"."Type" ASC ,"Project8"."UndertakingId" ASC ,"Project8"."TransportManagerId" ASC ,"Project8"."CancelReasons" ASC ,"Project8"."WarningDate" ASC ,"Project8"."WarningDeliveryDate" ASC ,"Project8"."FinishDate" ASC ,"Project8"."InternalProceeding" ASC ,"Project8"."AuthorityId" ASC ,"Project8"."PenaltyImposed" ASC ,"Project8"."PenaltyDescription" ASC ,"Project8"."PenaltyType" ASC ,"Project8"."isSendToEpuap" ASC ,"Project8"."ModificationDate" ASC ,"Project8"."CreatedByAppUserId" ASC ,"Project8"."LastModifiedByAppUserId" ASC ,"Project8"."Id1" ASC ,"Project8"."Id" ASC ,"Project8"."Status" ASC ,"Project8"."CreationDate" ASC ,"Project8"."BusinessCaseNumber" ASC ,"Project8"."C1" ASC
```

This is the plan proposed by PgAdmin III:

[image: PostGresql query plan]

[EDIT] My friend came up with such sql:

```
select premise."Id", premise."Type", premise."CreationDate", premise."Status", premise."BusinessCaseNumber", tm."FirstNames", tm."FamilyName",tm."CertificateNumber",premiseSum.NNCount,  premiseSum.BPNCount, premiseSum.PNCount from
(
    select distinct 
        premiseGroup."PremiseId", 

        sum(premiseGroup.NNCount) OVER (partition  BY premiseGroup."PremiseId") NNCount, 
        sum(premiseGroup.BPNCount) OVER (partition  BY premiseGroup."PremiseId") BPNCount,
        sum(premiseGroup.PNCount) OVER (partition  BY premiseGroup."PremiseId") PNCount
    from
    (
        select psi."PremiseId", 
            (select sum(count(sit."Value")) OVER (ORDER BY psi."PremiseId") where "Value" = 'NN') NNCount, 
            (select sum(count(sit."Value")) OVER (ORDER BY psi."PremiseId") where "Value" = 'PN') PNCount, 
            (select sum(count(sit."Value")) OVER (ORDER BY psi."PremiseId") where "Value" = 'BPN') BPNCount
        from "dbo"."Premise" premise 
        inner join "dbo"."PremiseSeriousInfringement" psi on psi."PremiseId" = premise."Id"
        inner join "dbo"."SeriousInfringement" si on psi."SeriousInfringementId" = si."Id"
        inner join "dbo"."SeriousInfringementCode" sic on si."SeriousInfringementCodeId" = sic."Id"
        inner join "dbo"."DictionaryValue" sit on sic."SeriousInfringementTypeId" = sit."Id"
        group by psi."PremiseId", sit."Value"
    ) premiseGroup
) premiseSum
join "dbo"."Premise" premise on premise."Id" = premiseSum."PremiseId"
join "dbo"."TransportManager" tm on tm."Id" = premise."TransportManagerId"
```

Which is really fast and has nice query plan, but we have no idea how to write this in LINQ and EF.
[image: QueryPlan2]

Answer (score 1):

Can't test on PostgreSQL, but in my experience EF in general creates inefficient translation for predicate version of `Count`.

What I usually do is to replace the predicate `Count` construct (`Count(condition)` with the equivalent conditional `Sum` construct (`Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)`) which translates to much better SQL (at least for Sql Server), so it's worth trying:

```
let NNInfringementCount = types.Sum(t => t == "NN" ? 1 : 0)
let BPNInfringementCount = types.Sum(t => t == "BPN" ? 1 : 0)
let PNInfringementCount = types.Sum(t => t == "PN" ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: It's faster, but it didn't change much, EF still creates 3 subqueries with nested loop.